# Calling functions in a c++ dll from c# that are defined in another dll

Tags: c#, dll, pinvoke, armadillo

I have already been able to read functions in a c++ dll that contains methods like this:

```
 extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport) Vector4  resta(Vector4 vector1,Vector4 vector2); }
```

I have been given a dll that implements the following function:

```
 extern "C"{ __declspec(dllexport) void pinverse(Vector4 skel[20], Vector4 result[20]); }
```

this function takes an array of 20 vector4 variables and computes the pseudoinverse of the matrix using armadillo routines, but I wasn't told which routines exactly, and when executing the function from c# i get a matrix of all zeros. I have also executed the function from c++ while keeping the armadillo dlls in the projecto folder an adding them to the linker input and I have gotten a result which is non-zero. So the question would be, how do I include the armadillo routines that are supposed to be executed on the c# code? Why am I not seeing any error message if the routine in the dll doesn't find the other routines from the library?

The syntax in c# I am using is this:

```
 [DllImport("C:\\Users\\PALMA\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\PruebaTest\\PruebaTest\\PruebaDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static unsafe extern void pinverse(Vector4[] skel, Vector4[] result);
```

and Vector4 is a struct defined like this:

```
 public struct Vector4{

   public static bool operator !=(Vector4 vector1, Vector4 vector2);
   public static bool operator ==(Vector4 vector1, Vector4 vector2);

   public float W { get; set; }
   public float X { get; set; }
   public float Y { get; set; }
   public float Z { get; set; }

   public override bool Equals(object obj);
   public bool Equals(Vector4 vector);
   public override int GetHashCode();
```

}

In c# I then proceed to create a class that calls the imported function like this:

```
 public static  Vector4[]  ProbarArmadillo(Vector4[] resultado)
      {
    Vector4[] skel1=new Vector4[20];
    Vector4[] skel2=new Vector4[20];

    skel1[0].X = (float)-0.505401; skel1[0].Y = (float)-0.0968128; skel1[0].Z = (float)2.54701; skel1[0].W = 1;
    skel1[1].X = (float)-0.547074; skel1[1].Y = (float)-0.0348387; skel1[1].Z = (float)2.5876; skel1[1].W = 1;
    skel1[2].X = (float)-0.532013; skel1[2].Y = (float)0.323909; skel1[2].Z = (float)2.60893; skel1[2].W = 1;
    skel1[3].X = (float)-0.468823; skel1[3].Y = (float)0.514958; skel1[3].Z = (float)2.63824; skel1[3].W = 1;
    skel1[4].X = (float)-0.642778; skel1[4].Y = (float)0.221897; skel1[4].Z = (float)2.49321; skel1[4].W = 1;
    skel1[5].X = (float)-0.765644; skel1[5].Y = (float)0.172945; skel1[5].Z = (float)2.27342; skel1[5].W = 1;
    skel1[6].X = (float)-0.793357; skel1[6].Y = (float)0.258069; skel1[6].Z = (float)2.04539; skel1[6].W = 1;
    skel1[7].X = (float)-0.802389; skel1[7].Y = (float)0.291529; skel1[7].Z = (float)2.01768; skel1[7].W = 1;
    skel1[8].X = (float)-0.405216; skel1[8].Y = (float)0.194607; skel1[8].Z = (float)2.75541; skel1[8].W = 1;
    skel1[9].X = (float)-0.297749; skel1[9].Y = (float)0.153036; skel1[9].Z = (float)2.85184; skel1[9].W = 1;
    skel1[10].X = (float)-0.164521; skel1[10].Y = (float)0.228597; skel1[10].Z = (float)2.93223; skel1[10].W = 1;
    skel1[11].X = (float)-0.105644; skel1[11].Y = (float)0.269457; skel1[11].Z = (float)2.98627; skel1[11].W = 1;
    skel1[12].X = (float)-0.551655; skel1[12].Y = (float)-0.15617; skel1[12].Z = (float)2.48071; skel1[12].W = 1;
    skel1[13].X = (float)-0.605082; skel1[13].Y = (float)-0.55405; skel1[13].Z = (float)2.37626; skel1[13].W = 1;
    skel1[14].X = (float)-0.659974; skel1[14].Y = (float)-0.880765; skel1[14].Z = (float)2.35654; skel1[14].W = 1;
    skel1[15].X = (float)-0.597098; skel1[15].Y = (float)-0.914582; skel1[15].Z = (float)2.29637; skel1[15].W = 1;
    skel1[16].X = (float)-0.448527; skel1[16].Y = (float)-0.184062; skel1[16].Z = (float)2.58483; skel1[16].W = 1;
    skel1[17].X = (float)-0.49097; skel1[17].Y = (float)-0.628932; skel1[17].Z = (float)2.57352; skel1[17].W = 1;
    skel1[18].X = (float)-0.515788; skel1[18].Y = (float)-0.962651; skel1[18].Z = (float)2.54876; skel1[18].W = 1;
    skel1[19].X = (float)-0.476598; skel1[19].Y = (float)-1.02878; skel1[19].Z = (float)2.53682; skel1[19].W = 1;

    skel2[0].X = (float)-0.505401; skel2[0].Y = (float)-0.0968128; skel2[0].Z = (float)2.54701; skel2[0].W = 1;
    skel2[1].X = (float)-0.547074; skel2[1].Y = (float)-0.0348387; skel2[1].Z = (float)2.5876; skel2[1].W = 1;
    skel2[2].X = (float)-0.532013; skel2[2].Y = (float)0.323909; skel2[2].Z = (float)2.60893; skel2[2].W = 1;
    skel2[3].X = (float)-0.468823; skel2[3].Y = (float)0.514958; skel2[3].Z = (float)2.63824; skel2[3].W = 1;
    skel2[4].X = (float)-0.642778; skel2[4].Y = (float)0.221897; skel2[4].Z = (float)2.49321; skel2[4].W = 1;
    skel2[5].X = (float)-0.765644; skel2[5].Y = (float)0.172945; skel2[5].Z = (float)2.27342; skel2[5].W = 1;
    skel2[6].X = (float)-0.793357; skel2[6].Y = (float)0.258069; skel2[6].Z = (float)2.04539; skel2[6].W = 1;
    skel2[7].X = (float)-0.802389; skel2[7].Y = (float)0.291529; skel2[7].Z = (float)2.01768; skel2[7].W = 1;
    skel2[8].X = (float)-0.405216; skel2[8].Y = (float)0.194607; skel2[8].Z = (float)2.75541; skel2[8].W = 1;
    skel2[9].X = (float)-0.297749; skel2[9].Y = (float)0.153036; skel2[9].Z = (float)2.85184; skel2[9].W = 1;
    skel2[10].X = (float)-0.164521; skel2[10].Y = (float)0.228597; skel2[10].Z = (float)2.93223; skel2[10].W = 1;
    skel2[11].X = (float)-0.105644; skel2[11].Y = (float)0.269457; skel2[11].Z = (float)2.98627; skel2[11].W = 1;
    skel2[12].X = (float)-0.551655; skel2[12].Y = (float)-0.15617; skel2[12].Z = (float)2.48071; skel2[12].W = 1;
    skel2[13].X = (float)-0.605082; skel2[13].Y = (float)-0.55405; skel2[13].Z = (float)2.37626; skel2[13].W = 1;
    skel2[14].X = (float)-0.659974; skel2[14].Y = (float)-0.880765; skel2[14].Z = (float)2.35654; skel2[14].W = 1;
    skel2[15].X = (float)-0.597098; skel2[15].Y = (float)-0.914582; skel2[15].Z = (float)2.29637; skel2[15].W = 1;
    skel2[16].X = (float)-0.448527; skel2[16].Y = (float)-0.184062; skel2[16].Z = (float)2.58483; skel2[16].W = 1;
    skel2[17].X = (float)-0.49097; skel2[17].Y = (float)-0.628932; skel2[17].Z = (float)2.57352; skel2[17].W = 1;
    skel2[18].X = (float)-0.515788; skel2[18].Y = (float)-0.962651; skel2[18].Z = (float)2.54876; skel2[18].W = 1;
    skel2[19].X = (float)-0.476598; skel2[19].Y = (float)-1.02878; skel2[19].Z = (float)2.53682; skel2[19].W = 1;

  //  pinverse(skel1, Resultado);
    pinverse(skel1, resultado);
    return resultado;
}
```

and finally I use the function in the main like this:

```
        Vector4[] resultado = new Vector4[20];

        resultado= Procesar.ProbarArmadillo(resultado);
        Recorder.SaveArmadillo(resultado);
```

Recorder is a class that puts the output on a txt file, but the file shows a matrix full of zeros.

Comment: Do you have any C# code? What is `Vector4`?

Comment: How are you calling this from C#? What's the PInvoke signature you're using?

Comment: [DllImport("C:\\Users\\PALMA\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\PruebaTest\\PruebaTest\\PruebaDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static unsafe extern void pinverse(Vector4[] skel, Vector4[] result);

Comment: Vector4 is a structure defined in the kinect namespace, like this:   public struct Vector4{}

Comment: You haven't shown enough code. We cannot see how you call the function in C#. We don't know which way thee data flows.

Comment: Your C++ function cannot work as intended when called from a C++ program either.  Its argument declarations does not allow passing an array.  Only a single struct, passed by value.  You need to get that working first before you try to pinvoke it.

Comment: Hi Hans, actually someone else provided me with the function and it works in c++ adding the dll to the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your struct declaration is a little off I think. I'm not sure how the marshaller treats auto-implemented properties. I would avoid them. I'd have the struct like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Vector4
{
    public float W;
    public float X;
    public float Y;
    public float Z;
}
```

And the p/invoke should provide directional attributes. There's also no need for `unsafe` which I assumed you added whilst trying things at random.

```
[DllImport(dllname, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void pinverse(
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 20)]
    Vector4[] skel, 
    [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 20)]
    Vector4[] result
);
```

Comment: Tried it, and worked like a charm, no need for pointers, also the struct worked without change.

Comment: I can imagine that the struct works. I personally would prefer to be explicit but that's fine. Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it working. I rewrote the c++ function like this:

```
void inversa(Vector4 *skel1, Vector4 *result){
 fmat temp(20, 4);

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    temp(i, 0) = (skel1 + i)->x; temp(i, 1) = (skel1 + i)->y; temp(i, 2) = (skel1 + i)->z; temp(i, 3) = (skel1 + i)->w;
}

fmat B = pinv(temp);
for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
    (result + j)->x = B(0, j); (result + j)->y = B(1, j); (result + j)->z = B(2, j); (result + j)->w = B(3, j);
 }

}
```

then compiled it in a dll project like this:

```
namespace pdll
{

extern "C"{ __declspec(dllexport) void mensaje(); }
extern "C"{ __declspec(dllexport) void promedio(Vector4 skel1[20], Vector4 skel2[20], Vector4 prom[20]); }
extern "C"{ __declspec(dllexport) void pinverse(Vector4 skel[20], Vector4 result[20]); }
extern "C"{ __declspec(dllexport) void inversa(Vector4 *skel1, Vector4 *result); }

}
```

and imported it in c# like this:

```
    [DllImport("C:\\Users\\PALMA\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\LeerDLL\\PruebaDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static unsafe extern void inversa(Vector4* skel1, Vector4* result);
```

then created a sort of wrapper function like this:

```
 public static unsafe Vector4[] Inverse(Vector4[] esqueleto, Vector4[] matrizinversa) {

    fixed (Vector4* skeletonpointer = esqueleto, inversepointer = matrizinversa)
    {
        inversa(skeletonpointer,inversepointer);
    }

    return matrizinversa;
}
```

and used it like this:

```
        Vector4[] resultado = new Vector4[20];

        resultado= Procesar.ProbarArmadillo(resultado);
        Recorder.SaveArmadillo(resultado);
```

and the output from the .txt file is:

[image]

The only thing I tried was passing the arguments to the function by reference, took the idea from Hans Passant, who criticized passing by value.

Hope this helps anyone trying to use armadillo routines from c#.

Comment: This answer makes me sad

Comment: Greetings David, I would like to know why this answer makes you sad.

Comment: It's not going to be useful to future readers. Needlessly uses unsafe. Doesn't really address the question.

Comment: Hi David, I am no expert in using either c# or c++, and I was just looking for something that would work, I use unsafe because otherwise C# generates a compilation error regarding the use of pointers. If you could show me a way around this, or point me to a tutorial I would be grateful.

Comment: I did show you how to do it. You did not appear to take any notice.